# Переменные Sass не работают

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

Исправлю вопрос:

Есть хедер, в котором написаны номера и кнопка:

```
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-contacts">
      <div class="header-contacts__phone">8 (123) 000-00-00</div>
      <div class="header-contacts__phone">8 (123) 000-00-00</div>
      <button class="header-contacts__button">Заказать звонок</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Стили "style.sass":

```
@import: 'header'
@import: 'variable'
```

Файл стилей шапки "_header.sass":

```
.header
  padding-top: 50px
  &-contacts
    display: flex
    justify-content: flex-end
    &__phone
      font-size: 22px
      &__button
        font-size: 14px
        color: $text-color-dark
```

И отдельный файл с переменными, который подключен к файлу style.sass:

"_variable.sass":

```
@text-color-dark: #353535
```

И gulp это все должен собрать в css файл без проблем (по крайней мере раньше собирал).
А сейчас начинает ругаться:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    src\sass\_header.sass
Error: Undefined variable: "$text-color-dark".
        on line 11 of src/sass/_header.sass
        from line 6 of src/sass/style.sass
>>                      color: $text-color-dark; } } }
```

Извиняюсь если вопрос получился длинным, но не знаю как по другому объяснить.

Comment: Добавляйте код, не картинкой, а текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные должны быть объявлены непосредственно в sass файле, или в файле, подключенном к вашему файлу. Судя по всему, gulp, а вернее компилятор sass ругается на то, что у вас в файле, в котором вы используете эти переменные, по факту они отсутствуют. Так же хочу заметить, что для табуляции согласно стандартам используется tab, ну или же 4 пробела, но никак не 1. Подсветка синтаксиса не о чем не сигнализирует, тем более, что у вас редактор, а не IDE, как вы сами сказали.

Comment: в следующий раз, задавая вопрос, прикладывайте текст ошибки и код, по возможности, не ввиде скриншота.

Comment: Исправил оформление. Я все перепроверил и попробовал другие варианты. Переменные работают только если прописаны в том файле где используются, и даже учитывая что все файлы подключены к главному, все равно отказываются работать из отдельного файла. Только эти переменные нужны, потому что цвета используются не в одном блоке, а по всей странице. И собственно нужна помощь в решении проблемы отдельного файла с переменными. (опять наверное не правильно мысль выразил, просто опыта не достаточно, что бы все правильно расписать)

Comment: используйте директиву @import , не должно быть никаких проблем с подключением переменных

Comment: Не знаю как так вышло, но вдруг все заработало. Поменял порядок подключаемых файлов, поставил первым @import с переменными и сразу все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Может в @text-color-dark: #353535 вместо @ нужно $

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).